# RestEasy Client connection pooling

Tags: java, rest, jboss, resteasy

We have an @ApplicationScoped bean where we want to use an injected RestEasy client and I am trying to figure out how to where the actual connection is taking place, when the connection pooling is coming into play and thus which of the objects in the chain to inject. I mean there is no point injecting a ResteasyClientBuilder if calling .build on it creates a new connection pool every time.

This is how I create the builder:

```
ResteasyClientBuilder clientBuilder = new ResteasyClientBuilder().asyncExecutor(es).connectionPoolSize(50);
```

I know that internally this is using a PoolingClientConnectionManager which is threadsafe so this will be compatible with ApplicationScoped.

Here are the further calls including the GET call (doSomething)

```
ResteasyClient client = clientBuilder.build();
IAction actionService = client.target(URI.create("http://" + actionHost + "/action")).proxy(IAction.class);
XXXResponse response = actionService.doSomething(a, b);
```

Where does the actual connection happen, where does it get popped from the pool and released back into the pool. I.e. Could I inject the actionService above and multithreaded calls to doSomething (or other methods on the "service") get a new connection from the pool each time?